# Filtering data for the last 3 months using DATEADD() in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-arithmetic

I am trying to show data from the last three months so have used

```
SELECT my_date::date AS my_date, my_col
FROM my_table     
WHERE my_date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())
GROUP BY my_date
ORDER BY my_date DESC
```

But I get the following error

```
ERROR:  column "month" does not exist
LINE 10: WHERE process_date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())
                                       ^
SQL state: 42703
Character: 651
```

I am not sure why it doesn't like MONTH, I am trying to use DATEADD() as shown here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_dateadd.asp `DATEADD(interval, number, date)`.

How should I be filtering data for the last 3 months and why does DATEADD() not seem to be working?

Comment: postgreSQL does it differently, have a look at this site: https://sqlserverguides.com/postgresql-date-add/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @VvdL for their comment.

PostgreSQL uses a different command. Changed to below and works.

```
WHERE my_date >= current_date - INTERVAL '3 months'
```